# How to rename table and change storage type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, types, rename

I first create a table which is set to store data in **MyISAM** engine. Later this table would be replaced with new table, but I still whant to keep this table and just rename it and change her engine type to "archive". I have try this:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable RENAME TO myTable-[DATE] ENGINE=archive;
```

Error which I get is: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENGINE=archive' at line 1 (1064) (SQLExecDirectW)")"

So how to in mysql rename and convert table from MyISAM to ARCHIVE engine?

Tnx for help

Comment: What version of MySQL you have?

Comment: @hemnathmouli version of mysql is: 5.5.37

Comment: `ALTER TABLE myTable ENGINE=ARCHIVE;` tried this?

Comment: @hemnathmouli Yes, and works, but, can you rename and change engine type in one sql statment?

Comment: Also, you can do it simply using object editor in free express edition of [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `test1` RENAME TO `myTable-[18-Aug-2015]`, ENGINE=archive;
```

Pass the new name as a string as well. Make sure to also include a comma ( , ) between the alterations that you require.

Comment: yessss, tnx dude, upvote and accept after 10 min - SO rules :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer looks like it could be the right track (I can't test at the moment), however, I suspect that you do not need the comma between the string and the ENGINE ?

Comment: @martin "Make sure to also include a comma ( , ) between the alterations that you require."